# alloc/release of Objective-C objects

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have Util class as follows.

```
@implementation Util

- (NSString*) getTodayString
{

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        // display in 12HR/24HR (i.e. 11:25PM or 23:25) format according to User Settings
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY/MM/dd"];
    NSString *now = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];

    [dateFormatter release]; ///???
    [today release]; //???
    return now;
}

@end
```

And I use the class

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    Util *ut = [[Util alloc] init];
    NSString* now = [ut getTodayString];
    NSLog(@"User's current time in their preference format:%@",now);

    [currentTime setObjectValue:now];
    [now release]; ///???
    [ut release];
}
```

I'm confused when releasing objects.

In getTodayString ::

Q1. [dataFormatter release] is necessary?
 Q2. [today release] is necessary?

I guess I don't need to release them as I didn't alloc myself. If that's true, when those objects are released?

In awakeFromNib ::

Q3. [ut release] is necessary?
 Q4. [now release] is necessary?

I guess I have to release `ut` as I create the object explicitly, but not suer about  `now` object.

- How one can determine when is the object is released?
- With python/C#/Java one doesn't care about this kind of deallocation of memory anymore. Is it also OK with Objective-C if I don't care about them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q1. [dataFormatter release] is
>   necessary? Q2. [today release] is
>   necessary?

**dataFormatter**: yes, you alloc/init'd it.
**today**: no, it was returned autoreleased from a factory method.

> Q3. [ut release] is necessary? Q4.
>   [now release] is necessary?

The same,

**ut**: yes, you alloc/init'd it.
**now**: no, it was returned autoreleased from a factory method.

> How one can determine when is the
>   object is released?

it's released when `release` is called on it, if `autorelease` is called, `release` will be called during the next run of the Autorelease Pool.

> Is it also OK with Objective-C if I
>   don't care about them?

No, it's not ok. If you do not clean up after yourself you will have substantial memory leaks, in the iOS environment that means a quite shutdown of your app. In a Mac app that can lead to eating up a ton of memory and not being a good citizen. This is assuming a non garbage collection environment. Ie most.

I'm guessing the heart of your question is you aren't sure when you are responsible for calling `release` and when you get an `autoreleased` object (or rather, when you are responsible for calling release on the object). It's by convention. If you call any method that returns an object that **does not** contain the words: init/copy then it is not your responsibility to call release. If you retain, you release   (There may be some more rules to follow, but that's the first one to really start understanding this, in my opinion). If you ever call alloc/init/copy, then you must call `release` at some point.

A GREAT teacher is Build & Analyze in Xcode. This will quickly point out where you screwed up and really help to understand what is going on.

Comment: Avoid making assumptions about objects being autoreleased from class methods. Always think in terms of object ownership, i.e. "do I own this object? Did I get it from a method with `new`, `copy` or `alloc` in the name?"

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you care about memory management in objective-c depends on the environment you are using. If you are using garbage collection, you don't have to worry about it, but garbage collection is not enabled by default on the mac and is not available at all on iOS. Basic rules for when something needs to be released:

- If the method you get it from starts with alloc or init, or contains the word copy, then you own it and must release it.
- If you explicitly retain an object, you own it and must release it.
- If the method does not contain alloc, init, or copy, you can assume it has been autoreleased. It will be released automatically at some point in the future, and you need to retain it if you want to use it after the current method returns.

Of course those also depend on any third party code following those rules with when they autorelease returned objects.

Comment: `init` does not affect an object's retain count, only `alloc`. Otherwise, you would need to release it twice.

Comment: @dreamlax No, but it is an indication that you own the object.

Answer (score 1):

The [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) are simple and clear. Do not think in terms of retain counts, always think in terms of ownership. When you ask yourself the question “should I release this object?”, ask yourself “do I own it?”. Commit the rules  to memory, and eventually they will become second nature.

It is extremely important that you follow the rules. If you ignore them, objects that you don't own may be deallocated before you are done with them (such as assigning objects that you don't own to instance variables, they may become deallocated after the autorelease pool is drained). Also, if you ignore them, you will end up with horrendous memory leaks.